# How to add pattern='\d*' for an input which contains spaces?

Tags: html, validation, input

I have some inputs in the form which from the visual point of view accept numbers only, for example input for "salary" or "phone number". However, I'd like to add some sort of input mask and make formatting for those inputs.

For example for "salary" input, I'd like the value to look like this **9 999** if user entered 4 numbers or like this **99 999** if users entered 5 numbers.

But at the same time I want to have a **pattern='\d*'** for these inputs in order for the user to "open" keyboard with the numbers only when user touches the input from smartphone.

If I do this, it doesn't allow me to submit the form, even though I trim all spaces before submission, it still says "Please match the format requested".

The question: is there any workaround to achieve what I need?

Here is a codesandbox with the example, please open from a smartphone to see the "keyboard" I want to "show" to the user.

https://codesandbox.io/s/masked-input-with-different-currency-patterns-forked-v8f.

Comment: I think [inputmode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/inputmode) is what you're looking for!

Comment: I haven't even heard about such attribute, but it works exactly as I wanted. Thank you very much!

Comment: Please post it as an answer if you want me to accept it as a correct one. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the `pattern` attribute to tell mobile browsers which keyboard layout you prefer might not work reliably. Thankfully, there's a dedicated attribute, [`inputmode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/inputmode), for this that should achieve exactly what you want.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('.money > div').click(function() {
    $('.money > input:eq('+$('.money > div').index(this)+')').focus();
});

$('.numberOnly').on('keydown', function(e) {
    
  if (this.selectionStart || this.selectionStart == 0) {
    // selectionStart won't work in IE < 9
    
    var key = e.which;
    var prevDefault = true;
    
    var thouSep = " ";  // your seperator for thousands
    var deciSep = ",";  // your seperator for decimals
    var deciNumber = 2; // how many numbers after the comma
    
    var thouReg = new RegExp(thouSep,"g");
    var deciReg = new RegExp(deciSep,"g");
    
    function spaceCaretPos(val, cPos) {
        /// get the right caret position without the spaces
        
        if (cPos > 0 && val.substring((cPos-1),cPos) == thouSep)
          cPos = cPos-1;
        
        if (val.substring(0,cPos).indexOf(thouSep) >= 0) {
          cPos = cPos - val.substring(0,cPos).match(thouReg).length;
        }
        
        return cPos;
    }
    
    function spaceFormat(val, pos) {
        /// add spaces for thousands
        
        if (val.indexOf(deciSep) >= 0) {
            var comPos = val.indexOf(deciSep);
            var int = val.substring(0,comPos);
            var dec = val.substring(comPos);
        } else{
            var int = val;
            var dec = "";
        }
        var ret = [val, pos];
        
        if (int.length > 3) {
            
            var newInt = "";
            var spaceIndex = int.length;
            
            while (spaceIndex > 3) {
                spaceIndex = spaceIndex - 3;
                newInt = thouSep+int.substring(spaceIndex,spaceIndex+3)+newInt;
                if (pos > spaceIndex) pos++;
            }
            ret = [int.substring(0,spaceIndex) + newInt + dec, pos];
        }
        return ret;
    }
    
    $(this).on('keyup', function(ev) {
        
        if (ev.which == 8) {
            // reformat the thousands after backspace keyup
            
            var value = this.value;
            var caretPos = this.selectionStart;
            
            caretPos = spaceCaretPos(value, caretPos);
            value = value.replace(thouReg, '');
            
            var newValues = spaceFormat(value, caretPos);
            this.value = newValues[0];
            this.selectionStart = newValues[1];
            this.selectionEnd   = newValues[1];
        }
    });
    
    if ((e.ctrlKey && (key == 65 || key == 67 || key == 86 || key == 88 || key == 89 || key == 90)) ||
       (e.shiftKey && key == 9)) // You don't want to disable your shortcuts!
        prevDefault = false;
    
    if ((key < 37 || key > 40) && key != 8 && key != 9 && prevDefault) {
        e.preventDefault();
        
        if (!e.altKey && !e.shiftKey && !e.ctrlKey) {
        
            var value = this.value;
            if ((key > 95 && key < 106)||(key > 47 && key < 58) ||
              (deciNumber > 0 && (key == 110 || key == 188 || key == 190))) {
                
                var keys = { // reformat the keyCode
          48: 0, 49: 1, 50: 2, 51: 3,  52: 4,  53: 5,  54: 6,  55: 7,  56: 8,  57: 9,
          96: 0, 97: 1, 98: 2, 99: 3, 100: 4, 101: 5, 102: 6, 103: 7, 104: 8, 105: 9,
          110: deciSep, 188: deciSep, 190: deciSep
                };
                
                var caretPos = this.selectionStart;
                var caretEnd = this.selectionEnd;
                
                if (caretPos != caretEnd) // remove selected text
                value = value.substring(0,caretPos) + value.substring(caretEnd);
                
                caretPos = spaceCaretPos(value, caretPos);
                
                value = value.replace(thouReg, '');
                
                var before = value.substring(0,caretPos);
                var after = value.substring(caretPos);
                var newPos = caretPos+1;
                
                if (keys[key] == deciSep && value.indexOf(deciSep) >= 0) {
                    if (before.indexOf(deciSep) >= 0) newPos--;
                    before = before.replace(deciReg, '');
                    after = after.replace(deciReg, '');
                }
                var newValue = before + keys[key] + after;
                
                if (newValue.substring(0,1) == deciSep) {
                    newValue = "0"+newValue;
                    newPos++;
                }
                
                while (newValue.length > 1 && newValue.substring(0,1) == "0" && newValue.substring(1,2) != deciSep) {
                    newValue = newValue.substring(1);
                    newPos--;
                }
                
                if (newValue.indexOf(deciSep) >= 0) {
                    var newLength = newValue.indexOf(deciSep)+deciNumber+1;
                    if (newValue.length > newLength) {
                      newValue = newValue.substring(0,newLength);
                    }
                }
                
                newValues = spaceFormat(newValue, newPos);
                
                this.value = newValues[0];
                this.selectionStart = newValues[1];
                this.selectionEnd   = newValues[1];
            }
        }
    }
    
    $(this).on('blur', function(e) {
        
        if (deciNumber > 0) {
            var value = this.value;
            
            var noDec = "";
            for (var i = 0; i < deciNumber; i++) noDec += "0";
            
            if (value == "0" + deciSep + noDec) {
        this.value = ""; //<-- put your default value here
      } else if(value.length > 0) {
                if (value.indexOf(deciSep) >= 0) {
                    var newLength = value.indexOf(deciSep) + deciNumber + 1;
                    if (value.length < newLength) {
                      while (value.length < newLength) value = value + "0";
                      this.value = value.substring(0,newLength);
                    }
                }
                else this.value = value + deciSep + noDec;
            }
        }
    });
  }
});

$('.price > input:eq(0)').focus();
```

```css
body{
    margin:50px;
}

.money{
    display:inline-block;
    border:1px solid #ababab;
    -moz-border-radius:3px;
    -webkit-border-radius:3px;
    border-radius:3px;
}

.money > div {
    display:inline-block;
    padding:8px 8px 8px 8px;
    font-size:14px;
    cursor:text;
    color:#666;
/*     pointer-events: none; */
}

.money > input{
    width:200px;
    border:0;
    padding:8px 4px 8px 8px;
    margin:0;
    font-size:14px;
    color:#666;
    cursor:text;
    text-align:left;
    outline:none;
}

.money > input::-ms-clear{
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="money">
    <input type="text" class="numberOnly" autocomplete="off" maxlength="4" /><div>$</div>
</div>
<br><br>
<div class="money">
    <input type="text" class="numberOnly" autocomplete="off" maxlength="6" /><div>$</div>
</div>
<br><br>
<div class="money">
    <input type="text" class="numberOnly" autocomplete="off" maxlength="50" /><div>$</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I appreciate your time and efforts but I'm happy with how the formatting/mask is working for me right now, the question was more about the keyboard. But thank you anyway